# how to create a javascript function to return a string made of all the values in the array separated by +

Tags: javascript

I am currently in an online bootcamp and I just started learning javascript and I am stuck on this simple question. Here is a copy of the question.

Create a function named plusesEverywhere. This function should:

take one argument, an array of at least two numbers.
return a string made of all the values in the array separated by +.

For example:

plusesEverywhere([1,2,3]); // returns "1+2+3"
plusesEverywhere([18,24]); // returns "18+24"

I was thinking of using the splice method but not sure if that is the best approach. Thanks for helping!

Comment: `array.join("+")` ??

Comment: @Pointy as far as I understood your comment would make a correct answer, my question is, why not answering ?

Comment: @facundo because I'm not sure I really understand the question

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**`Array.join(...)`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) in this particular case:

```js
var array1 = [1, 2, 3];
var array2 = [18, 24];

function plussesEverywhere(array) {
  return array.join('+');
}

console.log(plussesEverywhere(array1));
console.log(plussesEverywhere(array2));
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help out.  The join method wasn't even discussed in my bootcamp. Thanks for the lesson!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

Simple javascript:

```js
function plusesEverywhere(arr) {
  return arr.join('+')
}
```

Using an [Arrow Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```js
const plusesEverywhere = (arr) => {
  return arr.join('+')
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out. My bootcamp never mentioned the join method. I learn more here then in bootcamp.

Answer (score 0):

just for the sake of learning, you can also do

```
[1,2,3].toString().replace(/,/g, '+')
```

Comment: You can go shorter: `(''+[1,2,3]).replace(/,/g, '+')`

Comment: Even more: `[1,2,3]+''.replace(/,/g,'+')`

Comment: And the shortest I can come up with: `[1,2,3].join('+')`

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me out! I got tired of waiting for help online from my boot camp and his site has been faster and actually more help. I was playing around with the toString method but could not get it to work. My bootcamp didn't mention the replace method. Thanks again. I going to study what you did and practice it.